# TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object regex not getting criteria

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to filter using regex and it says `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object.` I don't know why but I think its not registring my criteria correctly here is the code.

```
def send_mail(email, password, message):
 server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
 server.starttls()
 server.login(email, password)
 server.sendmail(email, email, message)
 server.quit()


command = "netsh wlan show profile"
networks = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
network_names = re.search(":Profile\s*:\s(.*)", networks )

print(network_names.group(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.check_output` is returning a byte string (type `bytes`), instead of a Unicode string (type `str`).  To use `re.search` on a byte string, use a byte string for the expression:

```
network_names = re.search(b":Profile\s*:\s(.*)", networks )
                          ^
                          Note!
```

Comment: ok it returns `<re.Match object; span=(160, 189), match=b'Profile     : (what i need)\r'>`   How to I remove all of that and only get (what i need)

Comment: @An0nym0us-py read the [`re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects)...

Comment: I have read them and I haven't found anything about this

Comment: @An0nym0us-py Try `re.findall`.